# raspberry pi python. Button pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to python and raspberry pi, I'm trying to just print a button pressed log when I press the button, however, I keep getting many errors. and after hours of struggling, i'm at the last one which says and excuse me for such a noob question but it says invalid syntax. now have googled python syntax and according to me what I have atm is correct. could someone help me out and explain what is happening? Thanks

The error is :

```
File "test.py", line 1 syntax Error : invalid syntax
```

**test.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
input_state = GPIO.input(18)
if input_state == False:
    print('Button Pressed')
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Please include the Stack trace or the errors you're receiving!

Comment: Did you check you have RPi.GPIO in you environment?

Comment: How do i know that?

Comment: i know that GPIO comes with the rasberry pi

Answer (score 4):

Check your indentation:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if input_state == False:
        print('Button Pressed')
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: at which line exactly?

Comment: after `while True:`

Comment: this is just the copy paste, but i have it exactly as you posted in ur answer

Comment: When i run it just says "invalid syntax"

Comment: File "test.py", line 1 syntax Error : invalid syntax

Comment: I just got my raspberry pi, do i need to install the GPIO lib or does it come with it? it's not saying lib not found so i assume it's there. but i'm not understanding the syntax error issue. i rewrote it several times and same thing

Comment: How exactly do you execute your script?

Comment: i tried both in the Python IDE and in the rasberry pi terminal. in the python it's F5 and in the terminal it;s python test.py. in the IDE it says Syntax error and in the terminal it says Syntax Error at line 1

Comment: Make sure there is not a mixing of spaces and tabs in your code either.

Comment: One suggestion for you: **write code, Don't Copy-Paste**